# 我住宅在一座橋樑 的 附近。Does this sound idiomatic and natural, or stilted and artificial?

Tags: word-choice

I want to convey the idea: My residence is in the neighborhood of a bridge.

Initially I got:
我住宅在附近的一座橋樑。

Wǒ zhùzhái zài fùjìn de yīzuò qiáoliáng.

But after listening to myself saying that, I think I got the "de" out of place.

X de Y is the Y of the X.  So the neighborhood of the bridge is the qiáoliáng de fùjìn.

So I think I should say:

我住宅在一座橋樑 的 附近。

Wǒ zhùzhái zài yīzuò qiáoliáng de fùjìn .

I welcome any corrections of obvious mistakes, but I think the second version of the basic grammar and syntax is correct.  However, I am not sure whether this sounds natural and idiomatically correct.

Does this sound like a native Mandarin speaker would say it?

Thanks.

Comment: It should be "我家在橋的附近。".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`住宅`、`桥梁`
这两个词语太书面化了。

The more natural way is to say:

我家附近有座桥。/我家边上有座桥。/我家在桥边。

Comment: The first choice sounds very natural, and the second and third are also good.  Thank you.

Comment: @Rick: note that the first one, "我家附近有座桥。", the focus is on 橋 but not 家, it is like saying "there's a **bridge** near my house." The third one "我家在桥边。" is the closest one to your original sentence: "my house is near a bridge."

Comment: Is it the case that 座桥 is a two-character word meaning "bridge," or is 座 a counting word for bridges? Thanks.

Comment: @Rick: 座 is the measure word. "桥梁/橋樑" is a two-character word for "bridge".

Comment: @Stan. Yes, I also considered about the literal translation, so I added the third choice. But the third one sounds not good enough, isn't it? Do you have a better translation?

Comment: @shuangwhywhy I think the third one is good enough for a conversation :) And without context, it would be difficult to find a better one.

Comment: The most straightforward natural-ification for '我住宅在一座橋樑 的 附近。' is '我家在一座桥的边上。'

Answer (score 2):

- **My residence** should translate to 我**的**住宅. Alternately you could consider using a verb "I live", i.e. 我住在, or 我居住在.
- 附近的一座橋樑 means "a bridge nearby". 一座橋樑的附近 means "near a bridge". So use the latter because the former means you live in a bridge :)

Comment: Thank you. Your answer seems to suggest that the first form could conceivably be used in some other circumstances. When would it be correct to use grammar of the form: 附近的一座橋樑.  In English, we could say, "We don't know the address of the restaurant, but we know there is a bridge nearby."

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to express your idea:

1. 我住在一座桥附近。I live beside a bridge.
2. 我家在一座桥附近。My house / residence is neighborhood of a bridge.
   Why I don’t use “住宅”, because “住宅” is a noun, means “ house, residence”, , and it’s very formal, usually you may say “家” or “房子” instead.
   Why I don’t use “桥梁” is because it is also very formal, we usually use “ 桥” instead. 
   And why you can’t say 我住宅在一座橋樑的附近, because “住宅” is a noun, but here you used it as a verb, that not correct, if I translate it to you, it could be :“ My house in the neighborhood of a bridge”.